# Xcode 5 Simulator not displaying all views when loading a lib from Github that works on several other macs

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Trying to load this lib into my simulator: https://github.com/rnystrom/RNSwipeBar and when I download the .zip and open it on my simulator the bottom handle that is suppose to display doesnt display ....or at least its not visible , I say this bc if i click where it should be and drag up the log claims I am indeed grabbing the handle and the drawer thats suppose to be displayed is being displayed. I can do this in reverse as well ( clicking where the handle should be and dragging down causes the correct log messages to display so the bar is there , but its not )

What makes this weird is that it displays just fine on the other 2 macs ive tested on as well as on my iPad. Heres a video to show u whats happening : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5fTYwPINOM

and heres a link to the lib you can download and im sure ull find the handle shows up just fine :https://github.com/rnystrom/RNSwipeBar

anyone have any clue what could cause this? Ive tried reseting my simulator as well as doing a "Reset content & Settings..." with no success. I dont even know where to begin with a problem like this.

Comment: did you upgrade the project to iOS 7? it is written for iOS 4.

Comment: I figured this out shortly after posting , but yes that was indeed the issue.Though I still dont know why it was loading fine on my co-founders mac. If u leave a official answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to upgrade the project to iOS 7, since the original project was written for iOS 4.